# preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash - but I use #?

Tags: php, regex

I get the above error - and I have looked in any post for an answer. The thing is that I use # as delimiter and still I get the error. I have also tried with ~  and no other result.

```
$checkCode ="#^[A-Z0-9]{8}$#";

if (preg_match($Code, $checkCode)) {do stuff}
```

What do I do wrong - or where should I look for the error?
Thanks a lot for your help ! ;)
Best regards,
Louise

Comment: 1. read the manual 2. The order of the arguments does matter!

Comment: @Rizier123: 3. There is a difference between single and double quotes, especially when your string contains a `$` (as in `$#"`<-- ). Shouldn't matter here, but it _can_ cause problems if you don't pay attention to these things

Comment: Yes, thanks, I also thought it was... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
$re = "~^[A-Z0-9]{8}$~"; 
$str = "..."; 

if(preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) { ...}
// or
if(preg_match($re, $str)) { ...}
```

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

Comment: Thank you very much!! It helped in 30 seconds - I have changed the code - it worked and now I get the same error again...

Comment: $checkCode ="~^[A-Z0-9]{8}$~";

Comment: if (preg_match($checkCode, $Code)) {

Comment: I am really sorry - and I am really really grateful for your help. You're great! (I'm not so experienced...)

Comment: And I got it - another error in another place... Thanks again!!

Comment: @LouisePetersenMatjeka glad to help. Take a look at the manual, it's really helpful.

Comment: @LouisePetersenMatjeka btw, if the answer answered to your question you might consider marking it as resolved :)